# What's the way to get only the property value of an object using Windbg?

Tags: object, properties, windbg, dump, pykd

I'm doing dump debugging, using PYKD, and therefore I'm using the `PYKD` `dbgCommand()` for getting information on objects.

The problem is: the `dbgCommand()` results need to be parsed in order to be used, as you can see in following example:

```
source code : result = dbgCommand(("dt -c CStringArray m_nSize " + pointer_format) % (ptr)).split(' : ')
example     : dt -c CStringArray m_nSize 0x03966ce8
example output : 
  <application>!CStringArray
  +0x008 m_nSize 0n16
```

I'm only interested in the size itself (`0n16`), and I can parse the result in order to get this, but as I'm having lots of objects (some 100,000) this becomes very time-consuming, therfore I'd like to limit the result as much as possible.

Is there a way (using other display options, using other commands than `dt`, using native visualisers if needed) to get following situation:

```
dt <options> CStringArray m_nSize 0x03966ce8
0n16 // only that, nothing else
```

In the meanwhile, I've already arrived one step further, using `dd` command, as you can see:

```
0:000> dd 0x03966ce8+0x008 L1 // for a CStringArray, m_nSize is at memory address +0x008
                              // L1 means: limit the amount of answers to one byte
03966cf0  00000010            // the result only contains one line.
```

Now I only need to find a way not to see the memory address anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you want to use typedVar class from pykd?

Try:

```
print( typedVar('CStringArray', address).m_nSize )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
0:000> dt -c foo m_nsize
Local var @ 0x2dfdb8 Type CStringArray
+0x008 m_nSize 0n5
0:000> .printf "%x\n" , @@c++(foo.m_nSize)
5
0:000>
```